# how to add a user role from scratch using asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, model-view-controller, user-roles

I want to create a user role and identity from scratch and not use the default given when creating an individual authentication ASP.NET MVC project. When I research I get projects that use the default connection on the project. I actually don't know where or how can I add the roles when I created the registration and login from scratch.

Below is what I have done:

**Controller**

```
   public class RegistrationController : Controller
{
    //Registration Action
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Registration()
    {
        return View();
    }

    //Registration Post Action
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Registration([Bind(Exclude = "IsEmailVerified,ActivationCode")] Customer user)
    {
        bool Status = false;
        string message = "";
        //
        // Model Validation 
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {

            #region //Email is already Exist 
            var isExist = IsEmailExist(user.EmailId);
            if (isExist)
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("EmailExist", "Email already exist");
                return View(user);
            }
            #endregion

            #region Generate Activation Code 
            user.ActivationCode = Guid.NewGuid();
            #endregion

            #region  Password Hashing 
            user.Password = Crypto.Hash(user.Password);
            user.ConfirmPassword = Crypto.Hash(user.ConfirmPassword); //
            #endregion
            user.IsEmailVerified = false;

            #region Save to Database
            using (mymodel dc = new mymodel())
            {
                user.CustomerId = Guid.NewGuid();
                dc.Customers.Add(user);
                dc.SaveChanges();

                //Send Email to User
                SendVerificationLinkEmail(user.EmailId, user.ActivationCode.ToString());
                message = " Registration successfully done. Account activation link " +
                    " has been sent to your email: " + user.EmailId;
                Status = true;
            }
            #endregion
        }
        else
        {
            message = "Invalid Request";
        }

        ViewBag.Message = message;
        ViewBag.Status = Status;
        return View(user);
    }

    //Verify Account
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult VerifyAccount(string id)
    {
        bool Status = false;
        using (mymodel dc = new mymodel())
        {
            dc.Configuration.ValidateOnSaveEnabled = false; // This line I have added here to avoid 
                                                            // Confirm password does not match issue on save changes
            var v = dc.Customers.Where(a => a.ActivationCode == new Guid(id)).FirstOrDefault();
            if (v != null)
            {
                v.IsEmailVerified = true;
                dc.SaveChanges();
                Status = true;
            }
            else
            {
                ViewBag.Message = "Invalid Request";
            }
        }
        ViewBag.Status = Status;
        return View();
    }


    //Login
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Login()
    {
        return View();
    }

    //Login Post
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Login(UserLogin login, string ReturnUrl = "")
    {
        string message = "";
        using (mymodel dc = new mymodel())
        {
            var v = dc.Customers.Where(a => a.EmailId == login.EmailId).FirstOrDefault();
            if (v != null)
            {
                if (!v.IsEmailVerified)
                {
                    ViewBag.Message = "Please verify your email first";
                    return View();
                }
                if (string.Compare(Crypto.Hash(login.Password), v.Password) == 0)
                {
                    int timeout = login.RememberMe ? 525600 : 20; // 525600 min = 1 year
                    var ticket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(login.EmailId, login.RememberMe, timeout);
                    string encrypted = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(ticket);
                    var cookie = new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, encrypted);
                    cookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(timeout);
                    cookie.HttpOnly = true;
                    Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);


                    if (Url.IsLocalUrl(ReturnUrl))
                    {
                        return Redirect(ReturnUrl);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Request");
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    message = "Invalid credential provided";
                }
            }
            else
            {
                message = "Invalid credential provided";
            }
        }
        ViewBag.Message = message;
        return View();
    }

    //Logout
    [Authorize]
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Logout()
    {
        FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
        return RedirectToAction("Login", "Registration");
    }


    [NonAction]
    public bool IsEmailExist(string emailID)
    {
        using (mymodel dc = new mymodel())
        {
            var v = dc.Customers.Where(a => a.EmailId == emailID).FirstOrDefault();
            return v != null;
        }
    }

    //Verify Email Link
    [NonAction]
    public void SendVerificationLinkEmail(string emailID, string activationCode, string emailFor = "VerifyAccount")
    {
        var verifyUrl = "/Registration/" + emailFor + "/" + activationCode;
        var link = Request.Url.AbsoluteUri.Replace(Request.Url.PathAndQuery, verifyUrl);

        var fromEmail = new MailAddress("example@gmail.com", "Lifestyle Laundry");
        var toEmail = new MailAddress(emailID);
        var fromEmailPassword = "****"; // Replace with actual password

        string subject = "";
        string body = "";

        if (emailFor == "VerifyAccount")
        {
            subject = "Your account is successfully created";
            body = "<br/><br/>We are excited to tell you that your account is" +
           " successfully created. Please click on the below link to verify your account" +
           " <br/><br/><a href='" + link + "'>" + link + "</a> ";
        }



        else if (emailFor == "ResetPassword")
        {
            subject = "Reset Password";
            body = "Hi,<br/><br/>We got request for reset your account password. Please click on the below link to reset your password" +
                "<br/><br/><a href=" + link + ">Reset Password link</a>";
        }

        var smtp = new SmtpClient
        {
            Host = "smtp.gmail.com",
            Port = 587,
            EnableSsl = true,
            DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network,
            UseDefaultCredentials = false,
            Credentials = new NetworkCredential(fromEmail.Address, fromEmailPassword)
        };

        using (var message = new MailMessage(fromEmail, toEmail)
        {
            Subject = subject,
            Body = body,
            IsBodyHtml = true
        })
            smtp.Send(message);
    }






    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult ForgotPassword()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult ForgotPassword(string EmailID)
    {
        //Verify Email ID
        //Generate Reset password link 
        //Send Email 
        string message = "";
        bool status = false;

        using (mymodel dc = new mymodel())
        {
            var account = dc.Customers.Where(a => a.EmailId == EmailID).FirstOrDefault();
            if (account != null)
            {
                //Send email for reset password
                string resetCode = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
                SendVerificationLinkEmail(account.EmailId, resetCode, "ResetPassword");
                account.ResetPasswordCode = resetCode;
                //This line I have added here to avoid confirm password not match issue , as we had added a confirm password property 
                //in our model class in part 1
                dc.Configuration.ValidateOnSaveEnabled = false;
                dc.SaveChanges();
                message = "Reset password link has been sent to your email.";
            }
            else
            {
                message = "Account not found";
            }
        }
        ViewBag.Message = message;
        return View();
    }


    public ActionResult ResetPassword(string id)
    {
        //Verify the reset password link
        //Find account associated with this link
        //redirect to reset password page
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(id))
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }

        using (mymodel dc = new mymodel())
        {
            var user = dc.Customers.Where(a => a.ResetPasswordCode == id).FirstOrDefault();
            if (user != null)
            {
                ResetPasswordModel model = new ResetPasswordModel();
                model.ResetCode = id;
                return View(model);
            }
            else
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
        }
    }


    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult ResetPassword(ResetPasswordModel model)
    {
        var message = "";
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            using (mymodel dc = new mymodel())
            {
                var user = dc.Customers.Where(a => a.ResetPasswordCode == model.ResetCode).FirstOrDefault();
                if (user != null)
                {
                    user.Password = Crypto.Hash(model.NewPassword);
                    user.ResetPasswordCode = "";
                    dc.Configuration.ValidateOnSaveEnabled = false;
                    dc.SaveChanges();
                    message = "New password updated successfully";
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            message = "Something invalid";
        }
        ViewBag.Message = message;
        return View(model);
    }

}


Model
public partial class Customer
{
    public Guid CustomerId { get; set; }

    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int CustId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(254)]
    public string EmailId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(100)]
    public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }

    public DateTime? CreatedDate { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }

    public bool IsEmailVerified { get; set; }

    public Guid ActivationCode { get; set; }

    [StringLength(100)]
    public string ResetPasswordCode { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: where do you want roles? do you want to create roles or need attribute for controller to execute on particular role?

Comment: The scaffold from the ASP.NET Identity automatically creates the tables on your database since its a code first approach. If you go to your database then you would find AspNetUsers and AspNetRoles tables if I'm not mistaken. You can set your roles in that table. If you don't want to use those tables then you can make your own authorization filter attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Of-course you should need to use instance of RoleManager class, which will giving facility  for the create, check, and assign role for the users.

```
    private ApplicationRoleManager _roleManager;
    public ApplicationRoleManager RoleManager
    {
        get
        {
            return _roleManager ?? HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Get<ApplicationRoleManager>();
        }
        private set
        {
            _roleManager = value;
        }
    }
```

Then put following code into register method when you want to register new USER in table.

```
                if (!RoleManager.RoleExists("<roleName>"))
                {
                    var role = new IdentityRole("<roleName>");
                    var roleresult = await RoleManager.CreateAsync(role);
                    if (!roleresult.Succeeded)
                    {
                        ModelState.AddModelError("", roleresult.Errors.First());
                        return View(model);
                    }
                }
```